# python - c++ embedded interpreter and objects

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, python-embedding

I have a simple C++ program that starts an embedded python intepreter, imports a module and instantiates a class defined in that module.

I want to understand why the address of the python object (from the python point of view) and the address of the C++ object are different.

How are the python instance and the c++ view of that instance different memory addresses?

Here's some working code, using [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

using namespace std;
namespace py = pybind11;

int main()
{
    {
        py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
        py::module m = py::module::import("code");
        py::object o = m.attr("SomeClass")();
        cout << "[C++   ] object lives in " << &o << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```py
def message_from_python(*args):
    print('[PYTHON]', *args)


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        message_from_python(self, 'being created')

    def __del__(self):
        message_from_python(self, 'being deleted')
```

Compilation, execution and stdout:

```
$ g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++14 `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` code.cc -o code -lpython3.6m
$ ./code
[PYTHON] <code.SomeClass object at 0x7fb6926f1da0> being created
[C++   ] object lives in 0x7fffbed02588                   
[PYTHON] <code.SomeClass object at 0x7fb6926f1da0> being deleted
```

Comment: Excuse me for arriving late at the party, but how did you get to this -lpython3.6m flag ? I wasn't able to find any information about it and by luck I found your post which allowed my code working

Comment: @Joachim I'd love to be more helpful, but this was some time ago, I do not remember how did I ended up with that command line. I'm not very used to dealing with g++ so even now I do not know the rationale for that. I guess I took it from https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html?highlight=lpython#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a quick look at what a `py::object` is made of in its declaration [here](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/pytypes.h), you can see that the class holds a `PyObject *` as a protected member (inherited from `py::handle`). This pointer contains the address that you see printed out from the python side. If you could access it, you would see that

```cpp
cout << o.mptr << endl;
```

produces the same address that the python shell indicates.

Comment: I can access it! `PyObject *ptr() const { return m_ptr; }`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I'm not super swift at c++.